# How can I do this inner join properly in Apache PIG?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have two files, one called a-records

```
123^record1
222^record2
333^record3
```

and the other file called b-records

```
123^jim
123^jim
222^mike
333^joe
```

you can see in file A that I have the token 123 one time. In file B it's in there twice. Is there a way using Apache PIG I can join the data such that I only get ONE joined record from the A file?

here is my current script which outputs the following below

```
arecords = LOAD '$a'  USING PigStorage('^')  as (token:chararray, type:chararray);

brecords =  LOAD '$b'  USING PigStorage('^')  as (token:chararray, name:chararray);


x = JOIN arecords BY token, brecords BY token;

dump x;
```

which yields:

```
(123,record1,123,jim)
(123,record1,123,jim)
(222,record2,222,mike)
(333,record3,333,joe)
```

when what I REALLY want is(notice token 123 is only in there once after the join)

```
(123,record1,123,jim)
(222,record2,222,mike)
(333,record3,333,joe)
```

any ideas? thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
arecords = LOAD '$a'  USING PigStorage('^')  as (token:chararray, type:chararray);

brecords =  LOAD '$b'  USING PigStorage('^')  as (token:chararray, name:chararray);

bdistinct = DISTINCT brecords;

x = JOIN arecords BY token, bdistinct BY token;

dump x;
```

Comment: completely right, I should have done a distinct on my right side. Did that and all is well now, thanks!