# Equivalent of SQL SELECT in Pig

Tags: sql, select, apache-pig

I am new to Pig and am trying to understand the basic commands. I have a data set A which I inner joined to data set B. **I want to keep only some of the variables** in the resultant data set. How do I do that? This is what I have so far

```
A = LOAD 'science_scores';
B = LOAD 'math_scores';
AB = JOIN A BY Name, B BY Student_Name;
```

Now both A and B have a lot of other columns that I don't need. In SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT A.science_score, B.math_score
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Name = B.Student_Name
```

Can someone please help me figure how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use pig but I am one.  Since I can't answer the question, I upvoted it.

Comment: Whats the problem with your pig script. It seems to be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `FOREACH` and `GENERATE` keywords.

```
selected = FOREACH AB GENERATE science_score, math_score;
```

Comment: Additionally, you may also reduce the fields to keep only those that are needed for the join

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD 'science_scores';
B = LOAD 'math_scores';
AB = JOIN A BY Name, B BY Student_Name;
dump AB;
```

Please refer this below link.

[How can I do this inner join properly in Apache PIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790079/how-can-i-do-this-inner-join-properly-in-apache-pig)

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. My question is not about getting rid of duplicates. I want to select only the few variables that I need. I put the actual question in bold now.